# Query JSON data without node in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a column with JSON data in SQL server with the following values:

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID |                           Values                            |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | [{"Name":"Test1","Type":null}]                              |
|  2 | [{"Name":"Test2","Type":null}]                              |
|  3 | [{"Name":"Test3","Type":null},{"Name":"Test4","Type":null}] |
|  4 | [{"Name":"Test5","Type":null},{"Name":"Test6","Type":null}] |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to query the above table in SQL and want results as:

```
+----+---------+
| ID |  Values |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Test1   |
|  2 | Test2   |
|  3 | Test3   |
|  3 | Test4   |
|  4 | Test5   |
|  4 | Test6   |
+----+---------+
```

Comment: Also, you need to specify which database you are using.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: SQL Server 2016 or higher has built in JSON support. In older versions you will have to work harder.

Comment: We are using MS SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

Since you are 2014, and IF you are open to a Table-Valued Function consider the following.

Tired of extracting strings, I modified a parse function to accept two non-like delimiters.  In this case `'"Name":"'` and `'"'`

**Example**

```
Select A.ID 
      ,[Values]=B.RetVal
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract]([Values],'"Name":"','"') B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Values
1   Test1
2   Test2
3   Test3
3   Test4
4   Test5
4   Test6
```

**The Function If Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use SQL server 2016 or CLR functions and your json is fairly simple, you can translate it to xml and use [`SQL Server xml support`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-the-value-and-nodes-methods-with-openxml?view=sql-server-2014)

```
;with cte1(id, [values]) as (
    select 1, '[{"Name":"Test1"}]' union all
    select 2, '[{"Name":"Test2"}]' union all
    select 3, '[{"Name":"Test3"},{"Name":"Test4"}]' union all
    select 4, '[{"Name":"Test5"},{"Name":"Test6"}]'
), cte2 as (
    select
        id, cast(replace(replace(replace(replace([values],'[{"','<d '),'"}]','" />'),'"},{"','" />, <d '),'":','=') as xml) as [values]
    from cte1
)
select
    c.id,
    t.c.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(128)') as [Values]
from cte2 as c
    cross apply c.[values].nodes('d') as t(c)
```